# 'UseNativeMKL' is not a member of 'Control'

Tags: intel-mkl, mathnet-numerics

I am using v3.11.1 of math.net.
MathNet.Numerics.MKL.Win v2.0 is already installed using NuGet.
x86 and x64 folders are already exist in debug directory.
Related DLLs such as 'MathNet.Numerics.MKL.dll' and 'libiomp5md.dll' and 5 more are already exist in x86 and x64 folders.
'Control.UseManaged' is available but many commands like 'Control.UseNativeMKL' are not available.
How could I solve my problem?

Comment: What is your target framework/platform? Math.NET Numerics supports a lot of platforms, but native providers are currently only available on the full .Net framework.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 and .Net v4.6. I test it with other version of .Net but it just didn't resolve my problem. I could not still use 'Control.UseNativeMKL'.

Comment: Can you check what variant NuGet had installed into your project file? For .Net 4.6 it should have taken the one in "lib\net40", but I suspect it has chosen another one (NuGet regression?). Only the net40 one supports native providers.

Comment: I found my problem. Although it seams it is version 3.11.1 in NuGet package manager but I check DLL path and find out it is v3.4. I expect using nativeMKL could improve efficiency but it was 5 times slower. Using UseManaged gets the result in about 120 ms but UseNativeMKL gets result in about 600~700 ms and UseOpenBlas gets result in about 150 ms. Is it OK or somethings is still wrong?